# How can I push numbers in a list that read in text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that 10 numbers 0 to 10 written line by line(downward).

Such as;

```
2
4
5
1
7
6
9
0
2
4
```

So, how can I write those numbers in a list while reading?

sample of my code:

```
emptyList=[] # I need to push into "testnumbers.txt"
read = open('testnumbers.txt')
# use readline() to read the first line 
line = read.readline()
# use the read line to read further.
# If the file is not empty keep reading one lineat a time, till the file is empty
while line:
    # print line
    print(line)
    line = read.readline()
read.close()
```

After pushing numbers in list:

```
emptyList=[2,4,5,1,7,6,9,0,2,4]
print(emptyList)
```

I'm trying to get result like that:

> [2,4,5,1,7,6,9,0,2,4]

Comment: This is a trivial Python list manipulation exercise. Consider reading list tutorials.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the `list.append()` method after you convert each line to an integer:

```
emptyList = []
while line:
    print(line)
    emptyList.append(int(line))
    line = read.readline()
```

Comment: This code will not run unless there is another `line = read.readline()` _before_ the loop.

Comment: The code snippet I posted is meant to replace the OP's code's loop only; otherwise I would've also included the code to open the file.